# Definite integral - evaluation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What is the definite integral of $\frac{x^{300}}{1+x^2+x^3}$ in the limits $x \in [0,1]$ ?

Comment: Is it really $$x^{300}$$?

Comment: Yes. What is the problem ? Intuitively this should tend to 0. But not sure how to evaluate it mathematically.

Comment: It should not be very much different than $\frac 13\int x^{300}\mathop{dx}=\frac 1{903}$ since the major contribution of the integral is around $1$...